# how to get email\gmail data to activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, gmail, whatsapp

how to get mail buddy from email by choosing ?
i found some sulotion's here at stackoverflaw but when i finnaly found something that might work i gut permission error and as i understood from user here its blocked by google .

is it realy blocked ?

(java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{4284e9f0 15683:com.example.buylist/10158} (pid=15683, uid=10158) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL) - > this is the error . i add permission as asked from me and it still wont work .

if so , can u give me simple intenet that open gmail imbox (gmail built in app) .

and in related issue , i did get data from sms but can i do it with whatsup ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> can u give me simple intenet that open gmail imbox (gmail built in app) .

No, because [that is no longer allowed](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/08/gmail-gone-risk-undocumented-apis.html). Only fools did it in the first place, since it was not part of the OS, was not documented, and was not supported.